# Windows 10: Why I can't create a folder named "a" or "b"?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, anti-virus

Specification: Windows 10 with Norton Antivirus and CCleaner.

When I try to create a folder named "a", it disappear from the explorer just after the action. I noticed the explorer says a message "working on this", it take some time and then the message disappear too.

[image]

Now it seems that the folder doesn't exist. But when I try to create another folder with the same name I got the error 0x80070103.

When I try to create a folder with the name "b". Something different happens. The folder is changed to an unamed file with no extension just like the following image:

[image]

In safe mode I can do everything; also I can see the folder just like I created. Back in normal mode, I tried to use [Windows Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) but I can see which process is locking/using the folder. In safe mode, I can delete, create new files inside the folder "a" or "b" but in normal mode, I can't access them. No way.

I full scan with Norton Antivirus: no virus. I bought spyhunter: it isn't related. CCleaner Pro: it isn't related. I tried Scan disk, windows tool for correcting errors... no hell. Stopped Norton Antivirus: same situation.

It seems some software/virus is bug me down. I need folder like this because tools like SVN and Android Studio has idiosyncrasies about file and folder structure that just use this names.

Please help, can't just format everything and start again..

EDIT 1: A Test from DOS

[image]

The folder "b" disappeared and the folder "a" look like a file with no name and extension.

By doing a DOS "dir" command, I have the following result:

[image]

In this pic, "Pârametro Incorreto" means "Incorrect Parameter".
Arquivo means "File". Past means "Folder". It says 1 file and 2 folders were found but there is tree folders inside.

Comment: This sounds similar to some rootkit file cloaking mechanisms, but there isn't really enough information to work with, and its unlikely that a rootkit would behave differently in Safemode, and matching a pattern like `a`, `b` for hiding files would be way to simple to remain undetected. usually its like $SYS$... or some such.

Comment: If you use `cmd` does `mkdir b` work? What's the outcome of `dir /a` (list all files&folders)?

Comment: Same thing but "b" disappears, then "a" looking like a new file with no name and extension.. inverted from what I've described in the post

Comment: @FrankThomas I had the same felling and I started to be hopefull because it worked in safe mode. It also removed the suspection about SSD hardware problems..

Comment: Looks like a trace of a MS-DOS compatibility feature enabled in standard mode IMHO (a and b being both floppy drives). If this is the case, then the same kind of weirdness may occur with some other names like COM1 to COM4, LPT1 to LPT4 and CON.

Comment: @A.Loiseau it make sense too... I couldn't create any folder with those names too but the error is different... the explorer didn't not create any folder. The behaviour is different...

Comment: After a fast check, floppy drive letters are not officials MS/MSDOS reserved names if docs are accurate (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/74496 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247), but someone else is reporting the same issue with Windows7 on a microsoft.com forum which still lacks any real answer for now (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/file-name-problem/12639731-73b0-403d-8689-7db3e244829f).

Comment: I agree with OP; some 3rd party software is causing this. I can't reproduce on my machine, and the files he makes create successfully then disappear, or show missing filename. Very suspicious.

Comment: yestderday I tried so many things. Spent the whole day on that... I've even removed Norton Antivirus, TortoiseSVN and SpyHunter. I tried use  handle, process explorer, process monitor to check who was using the folder but I wasn't able to see.. Another information I had is that: from DOS a "dir" command counts the number of folders but won't let me see them...

Comment: Just wondering... What kind of drive is that E-drive? Is it a network drive that other machines have access to as well? If you test from safe mode, do you use networking safe mode and do you use the same locations? Is the behaviour the same on other drives/dirs (say you try to create c:\tmp\a or c:\tmp\b or something)? Just brainstorming here, probably not as simple as that but it needs to be excluded that it's like server AV functionality or maybe a virus on another workstation?

Comment: @SadBunny it happened at all drives, c:, e:, and any kind of attached storage... I found a solution.. but thanks for your vision. It was valid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was trying to stop services in normal mode which didn't run in safe mode, then I have accidentally solved the problem this morning.

Here in Brazil, a lot of users complain about GBPlugin - a technology most bank companies require users to use in order to access their bank account online. This GBPlugin consumes lots of resources and requires a highly skilled approach to be removed from the OS.

I tried to remove it following this [post](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/516502-resolvido-nbspnao-consigo-remover-a-pasta-gbplugingbieh/). Somebody named "DigRam" suggested a scan with [AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/) which had shown two suspect services:

1. 412f21e02ea37d13c378594fcbac2bd2
2. scan

[AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/) scan result has no effect on GBPlugin at all but had these two - suspicious. But after the Windows reboot I could finally see, create, change and delete the folders which had been hidden (in normal windows mode).

[image: I can see folder again]

I can't determine who was the troublemaker and I really don't care right now. Both were killed and the OS is OK now.

Finally:

- I couldn't remove GBPlugin yet, but that is another problem with an
  existing solution.
- I bought spyHunter which I regret.

Below, is the scanning result

```
# AdwCleaner v6.000 - Relatório criado 21/08/2016 às 09:08:22
# *Updated on 12/08/2016 by ToolsLib
# Banco de dados : 2016-08-21.1 [Servidor]
# Sistema operacional : Windows 10 Pro  (X64)
# Usuário : eduar - MOBISTATION
# Executando de : C:\Users\eduar\Downloads\adwcleaner_6.000.exe
# Limpar
# Apoio : https://toolslib.net/forum



***** [ Serviços ] *****

[-] Políticas do IE excluídas412f21e02ea37d13c378594fcbac2bd2
[-] Políticas do IE excluídasscan


***** [ Pastas ] *****

[-] RestauradoC:\Users\eduar\AppData\Roaming\ParetoLogic
[-] RestauradoC:\ProgramData\ParetoLogic
[-] RestauradoC:\Program Files (x86)\xtex
[-] RestauradoC:\Users\Public\Documents\dmp
[-] RestauradoC:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\Geckofx


***** [ Arquivos ] *****



***** [ DLL ] *****



***** [ WMI ] *****



***** [ Atalhos ] *****



***** [ Tarefas agendadas ] *****



***** [ Registro ] *****

[-] Restaurado[x64] HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{65416821-217D-44BD-9C61-F53398FB1B46}
[-] Restaurado[x64] HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{6DFC0DC7-FDC5-44C2-8B80-5977BA8F8ACC}
[-] Restaurado[x64] HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{E5AFF088-92F8-41a9-8CAB-E9CDCCE967AC}
[-] Restaurado[x64] HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4ABDD67C-44E3-42E0-816D-D7F0E54761DF}
[-] Restaurado[x64] HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{94915A56-4D71-4F85-B59C-CC040F5AC6F0}
[-] Restaurado[x64] HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{65416821-217D-44BD-9C61-F53398FB1B46}
[-] Restaurado[x64] HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{4ABDD67C-44E3-42E0-816D-D7F0E54761DF}
[-] RestauradoHKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{65416821-217D-44BD-9C61-F53398FB1B46}
[-] RestauradoHKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{4ABDD67C-44E3-42E0-816D-D7F0E54761DF}
[-] RestauradoHKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{34F4FEAF-4921-4B5D-8BE5-CA384BFFC2CE}
[-] RestauradoHKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{39A37965-0A96-43A3-870E-821FE5C84B0B}
[-] Restaurado[x64] HKLM\SOFTWARE\SmartPCFixer
[-] RestauradoHKU\S-1-5-21-3215691145-4218728392-1243681445-1001\Software\IM
[-] RestauradoHKU\S-1-5-21-3215691145-4218728392-1243681445-1001\Software\ParetoLogic
[#] *Key deleted on reboot: HKCU\Software\IM
[#] *Key deleted on reboot: HKCU\Software\ParetoLogic
[-] RestauradoHKLM\SOFTWARE\ParetoLogic
[-] RestauradoHKLM\SOFTWARE\SmartPCFixer


***** [ Navegadores ] *****

[-] [br.ask.com] [Search Provider] Excluídobr.ask.com


*************************

:: Chaves "Tracing" excluídas
:: Configurações Winsock restauradas

*************************

C:\AdwCleaner\AdwCleaner[C0].txt - [2494 *Bytes] - [21/08/2016 09:08:22]
C:\AdwCleaner\AdwCleaner[S0].txt - [2676 *Bytes] - [21/08/2016 09:04:40]

########## EOF - C:\AdwCleaner\AdwCleaner[C0].txt - [2642 *Bytes] ##########
```

Comment: In order to uninstall these annoying and useless bank plugins, I booted into safe mode, disabled their services and initialization entries, uninstalled from control panel and then manually looked for and deleted any forgotten files and registry entries. Will we ever be free from these accursed plugins?

Comment: Your bank requires an almost impossible to remove software? Sounds like a horrible 'security solution' & time to change banks! Also, Norton, really? Why put yourself thru that pain?